# Should i create style in render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am going to make my app have dynamic styles.
After user set a new size config and restart app, whole app styles will updated.
I will run update size ( load the config ) in app init.

here are my size.ts

```
class size {
    basicFontSize: number
    constructor(props: ISizeProp) {
        const { basicFontSize } = props
        this.basicFontSize = basicFontSize
    }
    update(basicFontSize:number) {
        this.basicFontSize = basicFontSize
    }
}

export default new Size({basicFontSize:14})
```

And in my app init page, will run size.update(newBasicFontSize), some of component updated styles but some not.

I think it should be the style created before init app, so should i put the style instance in render ? or any good suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put loading component until fully loading.

I don't know how your code works but how about like this?

but I'm not sure. I guess your actual update method does more than this.

```js
class size {
    basicFontSize: number
    constructor(props: ISizeProp) {
        const { basicFontSize } = props
        this.basicFontSize = basicFontSize // or update(basicFontSize)

        this.state = { styleLoading: true};
    }

    update(basicFontSize:number) {
        this.basicFontSize = basicFontSize
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      setState({styleLoading: false});
    }

    render() {
      if (styleLoading) {
        return <Loading />
      }

      // ... render ... this.basicFontSize
    }
}

export default new Size({basicFontSize:14})
```